# How to set correct frame for a custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have implemented a custom keyboard with XIB and '[UITextField setInputView:]', in 3.5-inch device(iOS7), everything is right; but in 4.0-inch device(iOS7), the keyboard appeared like this:

[image]

when I set the property "Autoresize subviews" in IB editor as following:

[image]

then result as following, the keyboard has been stretched.

[image]

The question is how could I detect and set correct frame of the keyboard?

Comment: Can you show some code about how you show the keyboard??maybe you could show keyboard like :`self.keyboard.frame = CGRectMake(0,CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)-CGRectGetHeight(self.keyboard.frame),CGRectGetWidth(self.keyboard.frame),CGRectGetHeight(self.keyboard.frame),)`. and do not autoresize subviews

Comment: I have solved, set [(UITextView*)tv setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable]; first, then the view's frame is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the correct way of autoresizing to fix the stretch image issue. Select the "Show size inspector" and then select the autosizing arrow 'left' and 'bottom' only to make it works well. Also no need to given frame sizes inside the coding.